# InDesign: How can I get paragraph contents with its characterStyles?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to write a very custom export script for InDesign (I have CC 9.2, but my target is CS6).

When I process a paragraph, I can get its paragraphStyle and its content. What I don't understand is: how can I get the content *and* the characterStyles of the content?

I'm looking at the docs, but I don't understand how can I descend into a paragraph and find all characterStyles and the text parts to which they are applied.

If, for instance, I have a paragraph like the following:

> My **nice** paragraph.

I want to know that `"My "` and `" paragraph."` have style1, while `"nice"` have style2.

The end result should be something like:

```
[
  {
    text: "My ",
    style: "style1"
  },
  {
    text: "Nice",
    style: "style2"
  },
  {
    text: " paragraph.",
    style: "style1"
  }
]
```

How can I obtain that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**TextStyleRange**](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc%5fTextStyleRange.html) property of a paragraph.

A TextStyleRange is one single continuous range of text with the same formatting. It does not matter to InDesign whether the formatting is 'local' or applied through a character style.

Obligatory Caveats:

1. TextStyleRanges see *all* local formatting, whether or not applied through a Char Style.
2. TextStyleRange formatting does not see GREP styles.
3. The last text range in a paragraph may (and usually *will*) happily contain the final return, as well as **any and all** text in following paragraphs that still have the exact same formatting. If you retrieve textStyleRanges per paragraph, check each returned text contents for the presence of text after a paragraph return. If it does contain a paragraph return, optionally clip off the excess text, and exit the loop for the current paragraph.

*very* Minimal example code:

```
tsr = app.selection[0].paragraphs[0].textStyleRanges;

text = [];
for (i=0; i<tsr.length; i++)
    text.push ('text: "'+tsr[i].contents+'", style: "'+tsr[i].appliedCharacterStyle.name+'"');
alert (text.join ('\r'));
```